# Flask_WTF: PasswordField disable autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, flask

How can I add a custom parameter to a field in a flask_wtf form-field. One of my requirements is to add the  `autocomplete="off"` to all password fields, but I can't seem to find out how I can add this parameter to a password field in flast_wtf generated form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass HTML attributes directly to form fields by name, with the exception of `class`, which uses `class_` to avoid the reserved word.

```
{{ form.password(autocomplete="off") }}
```

If you use a [macro](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates) like this to render your fields, you can still pass it through `**kwargs`:

```
{{ render_field(form.password, autocomplete="off") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preventing autofilling with autocomplete="new-password" : ✔

```
password = PasswordField('Password', render_kw={"autocomplete":"new-password"})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).